# Definite integral of absolute values over a simplex

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, absolute-value, simplex

I'm attempting to evaluate the following integral (note that $v_n=1-v_1-v_2-\dots -v_{n-1}$, and assume $n$ is even):

$$
I_n=(n-1)! \int_{v_1=0}^1 \int_{v_2=0}^{1-v_1} \cdots \int_{v_{n-1}=0}^{1-v_1-\dots -v_{n-2}} |v_1-v_2+v_3-v_4+\dots -v_n| \hspace{0.5em} dv_{n-1}dv_{n-2}\cdots dv_1
$$

The way I have been evaluating integrals of this kind (without absolute values) so far is by encoding the upper limits of the integrals using a delta function:

$$
I_n=(n-1)! \int_{v_1=0}^1\cdots \int_{v_n=0}^1 \delta(1-\sum_{i=1}^n v_i) \hspace{0.5em} |v_1-v_2+v_3-v_4+\dots -v_n| \hspace{0.5em} dv_n\cdots dv_1
$$

Then the delta function can be written as a Fourier integral:
$$
\delta(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i k \alpha} d\alpha
$$

If the integrand is a polynomial, rather than the absolute value of something, the integral can then be split into pieces and evaluated using contour integration.

With the absolute values, however, I'm quite at a loss how to proceed.

---

I have had two main approaches so far:

- **Approach 1:** Let $V=\frac{1}{n}v_1-\frac{1}{n}v_2+\frac{1}{n}v_3-\dots$. Then $|V|\in[0, 1]$, and thus

$$
|V|=\sqrt{V^2}=\sqrt{1-(1-V^2)}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \sum_{q=0}^p \frac{(-1)^q}{(1-2p) 4^p} \binom{2p}{p} \binom{p}{q} V^{2q}
$$

The integral over $V^{2q}$, however, has been very messy, and given me some quantities I'm not quite sure how to evaluate. (I can put more details if anyone is interested.) This may, however, be a useful route.

- **Approach 2:** I've tried to perform a change of variables in the integral to make it more approachable. The change I've tried is:

$$ w_1=v_1-v_2+v_3-\dots,$$
$$w_2= v_2,
w_3=v_3,
\dots,
w_n=v_n
$$

This appears to have a Jacobian of 1. Then I can go ahead an evaluate the integral using the Fourier approach I mentioned above. However, I get the wrong answer, which I believe is coming from me not altering the $\delta$-function correctly to work with the $w_i$'s rather than the $v_i$'s.

---

Through numerics (and some answers derived through use of Approach 1), I've come to the conclusion that $I_n\rightarrow 1/\sqrt{n}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and this is ultimately what I'd really like to prove.

Any help would be much appreciated. I can give more details on my current approaches if that is useful!

Comment: nice question! (+1). Have you tried some special cases like $n=2, n=3...$

Comment: Thanks! I've certainly tried $n=2$, which is easy enough to do by hand, and which gives $I_2=1/2$.

I'm keeping $n$ even, but even going to $n=4$ starts giving rather nasty algebra. Numerically $I_4=3/8$ and $I_6=5/16$. $I_8\approx 0.2734372$, though I don't have a nice fractional form for it.

Comment: Would the change of variables $w_1=v_1+v_3+v_5+\ldots$, $w_2=v_2+v_4+v_6+\ldots$, $w_j=v_j$ for $j>2$ be useful at all? The absolute value would then become just $|w_1-w_2|$ and the argument of the delta $1-w_1-w_2$....

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I think it will result in the same problem: we use $w_1$ and $w_2$ in the delta function, but the function also needs to incorporate the other $w$'s. Otherwise you could have values for $w_1$ and $w_2$ that suggest certain values for the $v$'s, but which are incompatible with the other $w$'s. That might not make much sense, so here's an example. Suppose that $w_1=1$ and $w_2=0$, which is allowed by our delta function. We could still have $w_4=1/2$ because it is an independent variable, but in terms of the $v$'s, this would contradict the statement that $w_2=0$.